# Use (.lib) c++ library file in android studio

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, .lib

I have thimble.lib file, which is C++ library that I built from source files found in this link:

http://www.stochastik.math.uni-goettingen.de/biometrics/fileadmin/thimble/doc-2013.04.30/index.html#sec_compile_unix

How to add thimble.lib in Android Studio?

Can I use this library in my application with the help of Android NDK?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use a prebuilt static library in your Android app through NDK. The prerequisite is that the library should be compiled with Android toolchain for the correct ABI (e.g. armv7-a). The **.lib** suffix is probably a typo: it belongs to Windows world, while Android and Unix use suffix **.a** for static libraries.

Your Java app cannot communicate with a static library directly, it needs a JNI wrapper shared library (**.so** file). There are quite a few tutorials to help you prepare the necessary setup, e.g. http://kvurd.com/blog/compiling-a-cpp-library-for-android-with-android-studio/.

In the nutshell, your wrapper will translate Java entities to native data types, and call the relevant functions exported from the static library.